# Animating change in EditText content using slide in and out

Tags: android, animation, android-edittext, listener

I have several EditText views that I want to animate a change in text of in succession one after the other. I would like to implement a slide out/in animation (old text slides down below and new text slides in from above).

I think this would require setting an animation listener to the slide down animation so that the slide in animation can be started when the slide down animation ends. However it seems the animation listener is attached to the animation itself whereas I need to know when an animation has ended on a particular EditText and to set the correct new text on the EditText.

Since the actual animation for each EditText will be the same, is there a way to do this with just the one animation object (i.e. Animation slideDown) or do I have to create a separate animation objects for each field (e.g. Animation slideDown1, slideDown2, slideDown3, etc)?